# Removing zeros from a numeric string in Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, zero

Suppose i have numeric string. I would like to remove all the trailing zeros and also the decimal point if necessary. For example -

```
'0.5' -> '.5'
'0005.00' -> '5'
```

I used this method :

```
s.strip("0") # where 's' contains the numeric string.
```

But for the `0005.00`, it returns `5.`, so how would i remove the decimal point if **necessary**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you could write a little function

```
def dostuff(s):
    s = s.strip('0')
    if len(s) > 0 and s[-1] == '.':
        s = s[:-1]
    return s
```

This strips all the `0`s and if a `.` was found and it was at the end of the string (meaning its the decimal point *and* nothing follows it) it will strip that too using `[s:-1]` (this strips the last character).

`s[-1]` gets the last character of the string. With this we can check if `.` is the last character.

This may be achieved with less code using a regex, but I think this is easier to follow

Demo

```
>>> print dostuff('5.0')
5
>>> print dostuff('005.00')
5
>>> print dostuff('.500')
.5
>>> print dostuff('.580')
.58
>>> print dostuff('5.80')
5.8
```

Comment: @DSM nice catch, I believe this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked with me to remove all zeros from my numbers, I would that help you.

```
word = str(num).split('0') #to convert numbers to list without zeros
word = ''.join(word)
```